# How to perform custom error handling for update command of ASPX's ViewForm?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm learning the use of ASPX's DataControls, and I have successfully used a FormView and its corresponding SqlDataSource to call stored procedures for select and update commands, that is, both commands are of type "StoredProcedure". I'm using Visual Studio 2012, with aspx pages and vb code. Not using ajax nor jQuery.

The stored procedure for insert or update performs validations before attempting any DML, If a validation is not met, the stored procedure would return 0 (false) in @psiSuccess (output param of type Bit) and a descriptive message in @psvMessage (output param of type VarChar).

I want the UI to inform the validation not met, so the user has the chance to correct the input and re-try, preserving the attempted values so only the wrong field has to be corrected. This is easily achieved when I manually create my forms, I just can't find the proper settings for these controls to do the same

I tried to evaluate the output parameter and in case of "no success", display the error message and **keep the ViewForm in edit mode**, keeping most of the user input to make it easier for the user to correct the failing field and re try.

I have used the SqlDataSource's "**OnUpdated**" event (SqlDataSource1_Updated(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)) where I can actually examine the value of the output parameters and change a Label's text to reflect the error message, however, the FormView returns to Read Only mode (the page actually reloads).

I have called the FormView's ChangeMode Method, but it appears not to work. However, I'm certain the code is executing.

**How can I keep edit mode or return to edit mode on the FormView?**

This is the code I have used in the onUpdated Event:

```
Protected Sub sqldsProyecto_Updated(sender As Object, e As SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs)
    Dim success As Boolean = e.Command.Parameters("@psiSuccess").Value.ToString.Equals("True")
    Dim message As String = e.Command.Parameters("@psvMessage").Value.ToString()
    If Not success Then
        lblMensaje.Text = mensaje
        fvProyecto.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit)
        Response.Output.WriteLine("<script>alert('" + message + "')</script>")
    End If
End Sub
```

The alert is actually shown by the browser and it contains the error message that comes from the stored procedure, but the FormView (fvProyecto) is shown in ReadOnly mode.

**Edit 1**

I performed a test to evaluate the order of execution of the events and it is:

```
<!--This is page Load-->
<!--This is sqldsProyecto_Updating -->
<!--This is sqldsProyecto_Updated-->
```

So, if the setting in ChangeMode is being overridden, setting it in Page_Load would still be overridden, since it happens before _Updating and _Updated events.
By this logic, testing for statement completion in Page_Load will always return false, since the action is performed after that, unless ASPX reports the events in some different order.

Is there some other property that must be set in order for ChangeMode to persist until page is rendered?

**Edit 2**

Here is the SqlDataSource, declared right after <body>:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqldsProyecto" runat="server" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="pObtieneProyecto" UpdateCommand="pActualizaProyecto" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" OnUpdating="sqldsProyecto_Updating" OnUpdated="sqldsProyecto_Updated" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings: cnxKanban %>" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false">
    <SelectParameters><!-- 2 parameters -->
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <!-- 11 input parameters -->
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="psiSuccess" Direction="Output" Type="Boolean" ControlID="fvProyecto$hdnSuccess" PropertyName="Value" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="psvMessage" Direction="Output" Type="String" Size="-1" ControlID="fvProyecto$lblMessage" PropertyName="Text" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is the FormView, declared inside a <div> inside <form id="form1" runat="server">

```
            <asp:FormView ID="fvProject" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqldsProyecto" Width="100%">
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="h2" />
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <a href="Default.aspx" class="goback">&larr;</a>
                <asp:Label id="lblProjectName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("projectName")%>' />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>...</ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <table class="formview-item-table">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 130px;">Name:</th>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtProjectName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("projectName")%>' style="width: 400px;"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Description:</th>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("description")%>' TextMode="MultiLine" Height="4em" Rows="3"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Kanban: </th>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="selectKanban" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqldsTableros" DataValueField="idKanban" DataTextField="kanban" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("idKanban")%>'></asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="selectStatus" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqldsStatus" DataValueField="idStatus" DataTextField="status" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("idStatus")%>'>

                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Priority</th>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ListBox ID="selectPriority" runat="server"  Rows="1" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("priority")%>'>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="10">10 (Maximum)</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="9">9</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="8">8</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="7">7</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="6">6</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">1 (Minimum)</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">0</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:ListBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Estimated duration</th>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEstimatedDuration" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("estimatedDuration")%>'></asp:TextBox> días</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Responsable:</th>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="selectResponsable" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqldsParticipantes" DataValueField="idParticipante" DataTextField="nombreParticipante" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("idResponsable")%>'  AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="">(ninguno)</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Requirente:</th>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="selectRequiriente" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqldsParticipantes" DataValueField="idParticipante" DataTextField="nombreParticipante" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("idRequiriente")%>'  AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="">(ninguno)</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="CancelButton"
                                    Text="Cancel"
                                    CommandName="Cancel"
                                    RunAt="server"/>                        
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton"
                                        Text="Update"
                                        CommandName="Update"
                                        RunAt="server"/>                        
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSuccess" runat="server" />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
```

So in the .vb code, in the _Updated event handler I evaluate the value of @psiSuccess, if it is false (zero) display the error message (which actually works) **and** keep the formview in EditMode, so the user has a chance of correcting the input.

Currently what is happening is that the error message is displayed but the FormView remains in ReadOnly mode (after the postback) so if the user has to change some input, they would have to click the "Update" button again and re-enter any information. When the update fails, all the data returns to the values currently in the database, so the user "loses" any changes they where trying to make.

Comment: Are you familiar with the ChangeMode method?

Comment: @DaniDev what do you mean by "familiar"? I guess I'm not. I used it as I thought I should after reading about it in the documentation. Should I have called it differently? in another event?

Comment: I see (did not notice it earlier, my bad). At any rate, to answer your question, "Should I have called it differently? in another event?" probably.  It all depends on several things such as if you are using Ajax. If yo are new to ASP.net you probably need to spend  little time understanding the Page life cycle events. When you submit a form it will perform a postback and your asp control (formview) will get retendered and take whatever attributes or properties last assigned to them. so in your instance your ChangeMode is (probably) getting over-ridden.

Comment: Try to follow the order of operation in debug mode (VS 2012 F10)  try putting the ChangeMode in OnLoad()

Comment: Your logic for evaluating success is not clear  "If Not exito Then"  is not clea? what is it that you are trying to evaluate?

Comment: You can try either ItemUpdating, PreRender , Mode  event handler or ModeChanging this will depend on the logic you are trying to evaluate and or how your formview control is configured on the client side. Maybe you can show your form code

Comment: @DaniDev, I updated to add the code fragments I think are relevant. The rest of the aspx file are other data sources for dropdown list boxes and such. The code behind is also almost empty except for the event handler I've shown, and the Page_Load and _Updating, where I simply write comments to the Response in order to "see" their execution order.

Comment: Ok, here's the thing: Your goal is not entirely clear?  when or why do you want to have the form remain in edit mode. what is psiExito ? Are you trying to persist the edited items if an insert failed?

Comment: If you want to preserve the attempts your best option is by using AJAX  which allows you to control which parts of the page get updated (look into asp:updatePanel) .   There are also many third-party components that make this a lot easier. Otherwise you would need to pass back all the submitted parameters. Another option is perform validation on individual input parameters.